# How to ignore order of search terms in regex (ReactJS)?

Tags: reactjs, regex, string, autocomplete

I have a form, through which the user enters input, and I'm trying to make an autocomplete for a form. I'm running regex on a `title` variable in ReactJS. The `regexEscape` function si being used to escape the string.

```
function regexEscape(str) {
    return str.replace(/[-\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&')
  }
if (title.length > 4) {
      matches = movies.filter(movie => {
        let input = regexEscape(title);
        const regex = new RegExp(`${input}`, "gi")
        return movie.match(regex)
      })
    }
```

Now, suppose user enters "Departed", then it matches with an autocomplete entry that says "Departed, The (2006)", but I want to be able to return "Departed, The (2006)" even if the user has typed "The Departed"

Is that possible? I need to be able to ignore the order of search terms, as well as exclude the comma I think, but I dont know yet how to ignore the order of the words

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build a pattern that will search for a string containing all words from the `title` string. It will look like

```js
/^(?=.*The)(?=.*Departed).*/gi
```

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=.*The)` - there must be `The` in the string
- `(?=.*Departed)` - there must be `Departed` in the string
- `.*` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible (basically, any text till the end of a line).

```js
function regexEscape(str) {
    return str.replace(/[-\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&')
}

const title = "The Departed";
const movies = ["Departed, The (2006)"];

if (title.length > 4) {
  matches = movies.filter(movie => {
    let input = "^(?=.*" + title.split(/\s+/).map(x => regexEscape(x)).join(")(?=.*") + ").*";
    const regex = new RegExp(`${input}`, "gi");
    return movie.match(regex);
  });
  console.log(matches)
}
```

Improving it further, if you plan to only match whole words, like `The` in `The` and not in `Then`, you need adaptive dynamic word boundaries here:

```js
function regexEscape(str) {
    return str.replace(/[-\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&')
}

const title = "The Departed";
const movies = ["Departed, The (2006)", "Then Departed (2006)"];

if (title.length > 4) {
  matches = movies.filter(movie => {
    let input = "^(?=.*(?!\\B\\w)" + title.split(/\s+/).map(x => regexEscape(x)).join("(?<!\\w\\B))(?=.*(?!\\B\\w)") + "(?<!\\w\\B)).*";
    const regex = new RegExp(`${input}`, "gi");
    return movie.match(regex);
  });
  console.log(matches)
}
```

Comment: That still doesn't work for me for some reason. How does that ignore the order? Because what I want is to be able to match "The Departed" with "Departed, The (2006)", so if user types "The Departed", "Departed, The (2006)" shows up too. Currently "Departed, The (2006)" only shows if the user has typed "Departed"